# JSch: How to ssh into a server using ssh-keys

Tags: android, ssh, jsch

I want to ssh into a server from behind another ssh server.  The gateway server requires a username/password and I can do this.  I am using a tunnel to get into the next server, but this one requires **only** an ssh key.  I've generated the key through PuTTY, so it exists for my username but I'm not sure how to retrieve it for my Java program.  Is it a configuration? i.e. setConfig("userauth.publickey", "com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey") then how do I use this or something else?  Documentation seems to be sparse and I appreciate any help. Anything I've tried gives me an error :"Auth fail" when I connect this session

Thanks!

The tunnel method I use is: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=ProxySSH so thanks to the guy who wrote it!

For context, I'd like to read/write to a server at my school from my Android phone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To enable [public-key authentication](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Public_key_authentication), you have to use one of the `JSch.addIdentity` methods.

These take the public and private key in the OpenSSH key format - so make sure you export it from PuTTY in this format. (JSch doesn't understand PuTTY's native format, though you could write an adapter implementing the Identity interface, parsing it yourself).

The identities added to JSch are global, not per-session. This is normally not a problem, as JSch will try all authentication methods which are supported both by itself and the server in order, and public-key authentication is normally before password authentication.

All authentication methods need a user name (usually the name of the account to be logged into).

With public-key authentication, the public key must be somehow previously available to the server. For OpenSSH's sshd, the public key should be listed in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. (If you have only one public key, simply copy it to this file, if you have multiple ones (each of which will be allowed), each should be on one line.)

So it should work out-of-the box after setting the identity.

If you want to make sure the first session uses password authentication and the second (tunneled) one uses public-key, you can use the per-session configuration, overriding the global one:

```
tunnelSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");

innerSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
```

(These are comma-separated lists, here of one element each.)

About the ProxySSH example, that is by me (with some help by JSch's author, Atsuhiko Yamanaka). I should add this information to the Wiki page, maybe.

Comment: Since the second SSH doesn't take in a username, what should I use for that field when instantiating the session? An empty string or null? i.e. jsch.getSession(WHAT_GOES_HERE?, hostname, 22);

Comment: I keep getting an Auth Fail error.  I have id_rsa and id_rsa.pub stored locally and I used PuTTYgen to export as OpenSSH key then use it in addIdentity(...). Am I missing something?  On the first server there is a /.ssh/authorized_keys file, which is a copy of id_rsa.pub, if that is relevant.

Comment: You *always* need a username for SSH - you can't log in into a server without this. (After all, the sent commands then have to be executed in some local user account.) And the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file (containing the public keys which are allowed for login) must be in the home-directory of the user as which you want to log in.

Comment: Of course! It's regrettable that I was stuck on such a trivial problem, but everything works perfectly now thanks to you.  Much appreciated!